# Streaming live to YouTube - adaptive bitrate?

Tags: android, ios, youtube-api, rtmp, youtube-livestreaming-api

In my mobile app, I would like to stream video live to YouTube via RTMP. From the Wikipedia article [Adaptive bitrate streaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_bitrate_streaming), when streaming videos, client is responsible for requesting a higher bitrate or lower bitrate:

> The streaming client is made aware of the available streams at
>   differing bit rates, and segments of the streams by a manifest file.
>   When starting, the client requests the segments from the lowest bit
>   rate stream. If the client finds the download speed is greater than
>   the bit rate of the segment downloaded, then it will request the next
>   higher bit rate segments. Later, if the client finds the download
>   speed for a segment is lower than the bit rate for the segment, and
>   therefore the network throughput has deteriorated, then it will
>   request a lower bit rate segment.

Since I'm concerned with live streaming upload from the mobile platform (Android & iOS), I wonder what the roles of the servers and the clients are. I would assume on YouTube's end, it has to request for content of higher bitrate? Or is the decision made on the mobile side?

Does anyone know which server YouTube uses for RTMP and whether it supports adaptive bitrate when uploading a live stream? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an adaptive bitrate RTMP encoding prototype on an iOS device using [VideoCore](https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore), so it appears that the YouTube Livestreaming API supports adaptive bitrate encoding for RTMP streams.

Comment: That library looks interesting, but really scant on documentations. Any resources available in learning how to use it?

Comment: @huggie I've been using the sample project (https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore/tree/master/sample/SampleBroadcaster) for reference.  I also monitor the GitHub Issues page (https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore/issues).  If you have any questions the developer usually responds within a few days.

Comment: Hi Jal, when checking out the sample code it looks like I'm suppose to see the camera output. However, I'm getting a black screen in the center. Is that normal?

Comment: Nope, you should see the camera view.  Can you check your debug console to see if anything failed to initialize?  Did you allow the camera and microphone permissions?

Comment: @huggie Check out the latest version of VideoCore.  Users have reported such a problem but the latest update (0.2.1.3) seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Thanks Jal. I'm a bit preoccupied with something else lately. I'll surely try it out. Thank you so much for your help and time!